# iteritems only giving one key

Tags: python, loops

So I have this function:

```
cached_list = []
def build_dependency_list(list, tree, cache=True):
    global cached_list
    if not tree:
        return
    if cache:
        cached_list = list
    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
    pprint.pprint(tree)
    for key, value in tree.iteritems():
        pprint.pprint(key)
        if key not in list:
            list.append(key)
        return build_dependency_list(list, value, cache)
```

But when I try to run it with some dictionnary I get this

```
{'drawee': {'fbcore': {}, 'support-v4': {}},
 'fbcore': {},
 'imagepipeline': {'bolts-tasks': {'junit': {'hamcrest-core': {}}},
                   'fbcore': {},
                   'imagepipeline-base': {'bolts-tasks': {'junit': {'hamcrest-core': {}}},
                                          'fbcore': {},
                                          'library': {},
                                          'support-v4': {}},
                   'library': {},
                   'support-v4': {}}}
'fbcore'
```

Any idea why `fbcode` is the only one being iterated?

Comment: because the function is returned after the first iteration

Comment: Please don't use the name `list` as a variable in code; you are masking the built-in type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *return* from the function during the first iteration:

```
for key, value in tree.iteritems():
    pprint.pprint(key)
    if key not in list:
        list.append(key)
    return build_dependency_list(list, value, cache)
    # ^^ part of the loop
```

So only the first key-value pair is produced, after which you recurse, and when the recursive call is complete, the loop *ends there*.

Comment: Small and simple error. Easy for others to see, fixed in two minutes. Thanks a lot :)